# no funciona mi codigo html en los navegadores

Tags: html

el problema es el siguiente estoy programando en visual con angular, cuestion que mi codogido que he tomado de ejemplos de videos de como validar un inicio de sesion con valores quemados que al dar click en el boton debe mostar un mensaje alert bueno en el video todo esta bien puse el mismo codigo lo cual deberia funcionar pero cuando activo el servidor y voy a mi localhost en edge o chrome y doy click en el boton deberia aparecer una ventana emergente que digo un mensaje pero no pasa nada doy en el boton y no hace nada mas, cosa que es rara ya que segui al pie el codigo y no deberia haber problema porque es un codigo simple, cabe recalcar que formatee mi laptop y no se si sea algun componente o actualizar algo que me falte

Comment: Me parece un poco extremo que hayas formateado tu laptop solo por eso (!) No tenemos forma de saber qué sucede si no muestras el código que teóricamente no funciona. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para agregar los detalles relevantes a tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya revisaste las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador (Ctrl + Shift + i en Chrome)?
a lo mejor tienes algún error en el typescript y eso impide que funcione